# Manufacturing Design Rule Check in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, drc

I have experience in schematic design but am new to PCB layer design. When I run a design rule check without Manufacturing and Testpoint rules, I get no rule warnings or violations. But when I include manufacturing rules I get a lot of rule violations and almost all of them are from the components themselves. I don't know how to correct that since I know the components are made according to the datasheets. Below is a picture of some of the violations.
[image: Components and violations]

Comment: It doesn't matter whether components are made to the datasheet spec if the design rules are set up incorrectly; you could then get all sort of problems flagged up. So, for example if your pad to pad spacings are set up as, say, 40 thou you'll get endless amuonts of errors!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately some of the Manufacturing rules need to be caught early and some are not so relevant. Ultimately, some of the Manufacturing Rules being checked for by Altium will need to be confirmed with the board manufacturer, and so there's no real point having them checked through Altium, if they will change again later when you discuss your requirements with the PCB manufacturer.

What I suggest is to check a reputable PCB manufacturer (or the actual one you intend to use) and look at what they consider important and a minimum requirement for manufacturing rules they specify. This will then also set your manufacturing rules if you wish to check for them. Unless you intend to keep using the same PCB manufacturer, these rules may then change....

From what you have shown us, there are some basic rules that cannot be ignored, like hole to hole clearance, but the sliver and silk to solder mask are less of an issue as these will not break your electrical functionality of your PCB.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected the hole-to-hole problem and am only left with sliver and silk to solder mask violations. What are some standard numbers for these rules?

Comment: If you have the space, do try and stay above manufacturer minimums, such as trace clearance and hole size. Doing the smallest of everything will be a lot more expensive in general.

Comment: For solder mask sliver you should typically be more than fine with .2mm, usually 0.15 is fine as well for standard designs. For high density designs check with your pcb manufactuer.